# why does my work look vastly different then the answer program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

the Answer program is on the left and my work is on the right. I am getting the correct answers based on the book I am using but I feel like I am doing it wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N65NC.png)

The instructions I had for modifying the original program are as follows.

Modify this program so it saves the three scores that are entered in variables named score1, score2, and score3. Then, add these scores to the Total_score variable,instead of adding the entries to the total_score variable without ever saving them.

I believe I have done that but I am unsure if I just got the correct answer the wrong way.

Comment: Please review [ask] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Your answer is fine and imo more readable than the provided program. But you can drop the parents around the assignment to the total score.

Comment: This is just a reordering.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue I can see is

> **add these scores to the Total_score variable,instead of adding the**
> **entries to the total_score variable without ever saving them.**

In your code you're initializing total_score as the sum of all 3 scores. That's not what the instructions are telling you to do. The instructions tell you to initialize a total score variable, and then add to it with each input.

I can't quote your code because it's in a photo, but it's lines 11-15 of your code. Compare those to lines 10-16 of the code solution.

EDIT: I just wanted to clarify, you might have achieved the same result as the specification, but if you didn't follow the instructions, then technically the code is wrong. Having the correct output and having the correct code are two different things.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly! What you are saying makes sense to me after I look at the Answer, but I dont know why it is correct over what I did. I am not justifying my work. I am just trying to make sure I understand what is going on since I do not have anyone in person to ask

Comment: @BeanFatherActualBeanFatherAct _"I dont know why it is correct over what I did"_: Because `total_score = score1 + score2 + score3` is adding all three together, and then storing the result in the `total_score` variable. The instructions say you should "add the entries to the `total_score` variable, which could be interpreted as "initialize a total score variable, and then add to it with each input", as this answer says. I wouldn't dock points for this because it's nitpicking semantics, but then again I'm not your instructor :)

Comment: If you were asked to actually _do something_ with the intermediate values of `total_score` (such as print the total after each input), then your way would be wrong because you wouldn't be able to print the total after each input since you add them all together in one go, but I'm sure if the exercise asked you to print the intermediate values, you would have done it the way it was expected.

Comment: @BeanFatherActualBeanFatherAct

I've been where you're at in terms of not having someone to ask. It can be really tough wrapping your head around certain concepts when that's your situation. My best recommendation is honestly to use chatGPT or some other AI for stuff like this. It's been a saving grace for me. Just copy and paste the solution code, your code, and ask it exactly what you asked here in the post. I'm not saying stop posting here! But it can be quicker and easier to do that sometimes :)